# removing double quotes and brackets from csv in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am trying to remove quotes and brackets from csv in python,I tryed for the folloing code but it can't give proper csv the code is:

```
import json
import urllib2
import re
import os

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

u = urllib2.urlopen("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/")
content = u.read()
u.close()

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content)
blog_posts = []
for e in soup2.findAll("a", attrs={'pg': re.compile('^Head')}):
    for b in soup2.findAll("div", attrs={'style': re.compile('^color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;font-family:arial;padding-top:3px;text-align:center;')}):
        blog_posts.append(("The Times Of India",e.text,b.text))

print blog_posts
out_file = os.path.join('resources', 'ch05-webpages','newspapers','time1.csv')
f = open(out_file, 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
#f.write(json.dumps(blog_posts, indent=1))
wr.writerow(blog_posts)
f.close()

print 'Wrote output file to %s' % (f.name, )
```

the csv looks like:

```
"('The Times Of India', u'Missing jet: Air search expands to remote south Indian Ocean', u'Fri, Mar 21, 2014 | Updated 11.53AM IST')",
```

but i want csv like this:

```
The Times Of India,u'Missing jet: Air search expands to remote south Indian Ocean, u'Fri, Mar 21, 2014 | Updated 11.53AM IST
```

So what can i do for getting this type of csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writer.writerow()` expects a sequence containing strings or numbers. You are passing a sequence of tuples. Use `Writer.writerows()` instead.